# tcolorbox for source code (read from file) and ouput (read from file) in lower part

Tags: tcolorbox, tcbinputlisting

I'm looking for a way to use tcolorbox to typeset some source code from a file and its output (read from a file) in the lower part of the same box and I can't find how to do this in the documentation.  It is possible and how?

Comment: The source code is LaTeX itself?

Comment: Of course not, it would be too easy.  In my case, it's an SQL SELECT statement and I want to show the output of the query but I'd like to use this also for showing C code (or any other programming language) and the output of the program.

Comment: Please provide a MWE as a starter then.

Comment: Where is the problem? Can't you do two \lstinputlisting?

Comment: This would create two boxes. I'd like to use the upper and lower parts of the same box.

Answer (score 6):

Too long for a comment: There is no problem to use \lstinputlisting inside a tcolorbox:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
\lstinputlisting{xfp.sty}

\tcblower
\lstinputlisting{xfp.sty}

\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was so trying to use \newtcbinputlisting that I didn't even think about that.  So simple! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `\newtcbinputlisting`, a possible solution could be to use `listing and comment`, where `comment` inputs the results file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{listings}

\newtcbinputlisting{\mylisting}[3][]{%
listing file={#2},
title=A nice listing with results,
listing and comment,
comment={\lstinputlisting{#3}}
#1
}

\begin{document}
\mylisting{368162.tex}{368162.tex}

\end{document}
```

[image]